# Jsoup in Android, crash with NoClassDefFound error

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to load a division in a HTML webpage so first i started with simple HTML code with divisions in it...to extract the division I am trying to parse the HTML string using `Jsoup.parse()` method but it is not working. I already added Jsoup libraries in the project. But whenever I
try to parse it using

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
```

or

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect(str).get();`
```

It is showing `Application has unexpectedly stopped working`.
i don't know where the problem is.

```
package com.example.kdp;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Search extends Activity{

    Button bSearch;
    EditText tSearch;
    TextView showText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        bSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearch);
        tSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tSearch);
        showText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);
        bSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            public void onClick(View v) {   


                final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);   
                web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                web.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
                web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);             
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {                         

                           web.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {                                                      
                                    String str="<html><div class='subfooter'>Total expense:$100</div><div class='subheading'>Total revenue:$32</div></html>";
                                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
                                    //Document doc = Jsoup.connect(str).get();
                                    showText.setText(str);                          
                                    web.loadData(str,"html/text","utf-8");

                              }
                          });
                      }
                  }).start();                 

            }
        });


    }


}
```

LogCat:

```
04-28 16:47:56.391: I/dalvikvm(535): Could not find method 

org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect,
referenced from method com.example.kdp.Search$1$1.run 
04-28 16:47:56.391: W/dalvikvm(535): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3591: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection; 04-28 16:47:56.421: W/dalvikvm(535): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 
04-28 16:47:56.421: E/AndroidRuntime(535): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14 04-28 16:47:56.421: E/AndroidRuntime(535): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup 
04-28 16:47:56.421: E/AndroidRuntime(535)
```

Comment: Show your LogCat  / stack trace.

Comment: Also, use `AsyncTask` instead of threads.

Comment: 04-28 16:47:56.391: I/dalvikvm(535): Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.example.kdp.Search$1$1.run
04-28 16:47:56.391: W/dalvikvm(535): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3591: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;
04-28 16:47:56.421: W/dalvikvm(535): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-28 16:47:56.421: E/AndroidRuntime(535): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14
04-28 16:47:56.421: E/AndroidRuntime(535): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
04-28 16:47:56.421: E/AndroidRuntime(535):

Comment: This means that Jsoup library is not properly included in your project. Did you add it to libraries scection in Eclipse / Android Studio ? Also, in the future, please edit Logs or code into the question, as it is hard to read in comments.

Comment: Also, why are you using Jsoup if you are not actually doing anythoing with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE USE

```
showText.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

instead of

```
showText.setText(str);
```

as Html.fromHtml will give you what you expect.

Comment: the problem is not with setText() method but it is with   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str); it is not parsing into document format when i use above method....thanks for reply

Comment: @vjnan369 if you are using the way i suggested I don't think that you should use Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str); try the same for once if you wish and comment the line Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);

Comment: got it.....thanks....but how can i get particular division html code with class with above parsing

Comment: @vjnan369 Sorry I havn't tried it ever.If the post was useful to solve your issue then I'm happy.Happy coding